# Same query doesn't run on restored Cassandra database

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql3, cqlsh

I am working on Cassandra migration.
I built a new Cassandra cluster - Cassandra 2.1.8 on Ubuntu 14.04. Database was restored from snapshots.
Source Cassandra cluster is also version 2.1.8.

I am facing with this weird issue.
On the original cluster I can run following query using cqlsh without any errors. cqlsh is version 5.0.1.

`SELECT * FROM "featureitems" WHERE "categoryId" = 2 LIMIT 100;`

On a new cluster same query throws error:

`InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Undefined name categoryId in where clause ('categoryId = 2')"`

but it runs perfectly fine when I remove double quotes

`SELECT * FROM featureitems WHERE categoryId = 2 LIMIT 100;`

It looks like some configuration issue, but I don't know where to look. Any suggestion in that sense is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra converts all column/table/keyspace names to lowercase if not provided in double quotes.

So if you need uppercase character in column/table/keyspace name use double quotes.

You can use `DESC TABLE featureitems` command to describe table.

In your first query you have enclosed `categoryId` in double quotes, hence it looks for column with capital I.

In your second query  `categoryId` is not enclosed in double quotes, hence it will be converted to `categoryid`... which is present in table and hence working.

Comment: I compared the original table definition with a new one and I can see that in new table names were converted to lowercase which is causing the issue. It is issue with my tablespace creation script which I need to look into.
Thank you for your help.